# Function to paste killring after the current line (like "p" in vim)

Tags: yank

I'm trying to write a very simple function to replicate the Vim 'p' command. 
This is, paste some text after the current line.

I've been googling for a while and haven't found a function to achieve this, which I think it's very strange as I consider this quite handy!

I'm aware of the awesome Evil-mode, but I just require only this functionality to be happy :-)

So far this is what I have:

```
(defun paste-after-line ()
  (interactive)
  (prelude-smart-open-line nil) ;; This function opens a new line below
  (yank))
```

It works, but if the copied text has a line ending, then the yanked text also adds an empty line below the text and places the cursor there.

Does anyone knows if is there a way to yank some text excluding any new line on it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might want a [yank handler](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Yanking.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wonderful function named `delete-blank-lines`.

```el
(defun paste-after-line ()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line nil)
  (newline-and-indent)
  (yank)
  (delete-blank-lines))
```